# como se desvicula firebase desde sdk de android

Tags: android-studio, sdk

Muy tardes amigo necesito desvincular una conexión de firebase  Todo esto lo hice desde el SDK de Android. pero me quedo mal configurado y ahora quiero quitar esa conexión y agregarle una nueva que esta vez la hice mejor. Muchas gracias de antemano

[image: Desvincular FireBase desde el sdk de android]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes entrar a la consola Firebase, ubicar tu proyecto y la aplicaciòn.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Da clic en el botòn que indica eliminar la aplicaciòn

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma eliminarìas la relaciòn.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Android Studio cierra el proyecto y vuelvelo a abrir nuevamente, de esta forma podràs ver que se realizo la desconexiòn.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorgesys si me sirvio pero  Fcm me siguio vinculado. en  ese caso que puedo hacer? gracias amigo por tu colaboración.

Comment: Hola donde te muestra que continua vinculado?

Comment: Amigo vinculado ya no aparece pero el FCM sigue en verde.. no se desvincula.. eso no es necesario? o se sigue teniendo la dependencia..sigue en verde.

Comment: y tampoco me deja volver a vincularlo me dice que no encuentra el archivo google-service.json

Answer (score 0):

Aparte de eliminar el proyecto de la consola de Firebase, lo que debes hacer después en el android studio seria eliminar el archivo google-service.json y quitar la implementación también de firebase, con eso quedaría limpio y lo que deberías hacer es hacer la vinculación nuevamente ya sea de forma manual o de forma con la guía que te proporciona firebase.